# Fql query for nearest location all public events

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

> hello i am new in android. i want to search all public event which held in my city i.e. nearest location from graph API of Facebook. can anybody suggest me FQL query for this.
>   the help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can help,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

with FQL location_post

Comment: can u give me example for this...i want public event not post location.